# Inertia of an elliptic curve with potentially good reduction

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, local-field

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}_p$, $p\geq5$ be an elliptic curve with additive potentially good reduction. Then there is a unique, minimal, finite and totally ramified extension $K$ such that $E/K$ has good reduction.

Now, given that $E$ has potentially good reduction, it has good reduction if and only if the valuation of the discriminant is divisible by $12$. This means the inertia group has order dividing $12$. Since we have assumed that $p\geq5$, there is no wild inertia which means he inertia group is cyclic of order dividing $12$.

However, it seems that it cannot have order $12$ due to the characteristic polynomial of the Frobenius being quadratic and the minimal polynomial of a primitive $12th$ root of unity being quartic. Can anyone please elaborate on this and how that helps?

Comment: I'm not sure it is true that $E$ has potentially good reduction iff the valuation of the discriminant is divisible by $12$. For example, In Silverman's book, example VII.5.2, it is stated that the curve $y^2=x^3+5$ has additive potentially good reduction over $\mathbb Q_5$, but the $5$-adic valuation of the discriminant is $2$.

Comment: @Ferra you're right, $E$ has potentially good reduction if and only if the j-invariant is integral. I meant to say about when $E$ attains good reduction so I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Actually, the curve I mentioned you attains good reduction over $\mathbb Q_5(\sqrt[6]{5})$...

Comment: @Ferra In that case the discriminant is $25=(\sqrt[6]{5})^{12})$ so now has valuation 12 over $\mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt[6]{5})$ hence has good reduction as you say. I should have mentioned you need to take the normalised valuation on $K$.

Comment: This fact essentially comes from Silverman VII.5.1a except we drop the requirement that $E$ is given by a minimal Weierstrass equation.